# typescript+reactjs+ requirejs: how to import react-dom into typescript

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, typescript, require

I am using typescript + react.js. In visual studio (2015) , in the project properties --> Typescript build --> Module System: I have checked AMD so I am using requirejs to import my modules.

I have a main.txs file where I render my main component into the body tag, some thing like:

```
React.render(<MyMainComponent />, my_body_element);
```

Now on top of my file I have made the proper import statements:

```
import react = require('react');
import reactdom = require('react-dom'); 
import some_library = require('./some_library')
```

(sos: I am using DefinitelyTyped -tsd- to import type definitions)

After build (in visual studio) there is a main.js file generated with the javascript emitted as followed:

```
define(["require", "exports", 'react', './some_library'], function (require, exports, react, some_library) { 

..... code goes here .....

}
```

You can see that require statement for react-dom has not been generated. Why is the require statement for react-dom not generated within the emitted main.js file?

The consequence is that I am not able to use ReactDom in my code.

Has any one been able to use react, react-dom, requirejs and typescript? (presumably in a visual studio environment?)

How can I tell visual studio to emit a require statement for react-dom?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the code you wrote

```
React.render(<MyMainComponent />, my_body_element);
```

Then you're not using `reactdom`, so the compiler thinks it's safe to remove the import.

You probably want to write

```
reactdom.render(<MyMainComponent />, my_body_element);
```

If there's something else going on where you want to import `react-dom` but not use it (why?), use the `amd-dependency` tag to explicitly add it to the imports list.

Comment: Thanks fro your answer. But every time I use ReactDom, I receive an exeption : cannot use function render of undefined... --> meaning ReactDom is undefined (because it has not been imported). I will definitely have a look to this "amd-dependency" tag. first-time I hear about it.

Comment: That means the import is failing at runtime. Have you checked your browser console for 404 messages or errors from requirejs?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no 404 message from my browser...I am really at lost here...2 things come in my mind: either my solution is corrupted ( I was able to run a very simple project with only reat.js, react-dom.js and a main.txs file. react-dom  was correctly loaded. But my project is quite huge I am not able to start from scratch) The other possible is that I am making a mistake in the way I declare in require.js that react-dom depends on react.js